# Text classification with neural network

Tags: java, text, machine-learning, neural-network, feature-selection

Can someone tell me how can I classify some text messages using neural network.?
Is there any examples? how do I preprocess text messages to train the neural network?

Thanks

Comment: question is too vague, show some effort and ask specific question.

Comment: Do you know [weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) ?

Answer (score 4):

Whilst your question is pretty vague, I'll give it a go, but it really depends on what you want to do.  If you're simply trying to extract features and determine if:

- Your feature selection is good
- What machine learning algorithm/structure to use

Then, Weka is an awesome option.  Here's a link to a set of tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd5HwYYOz2U

Basically, you need to write a program to extract what features you consider relevant and what the possible "classes" of your data are and then output a .arff file.  By class, I mean that if you're trying to decide if a sentence is about an fruit or a vegetable, then your two classes would be fruit and vegetable.  It may look complicated in the beginning, but it's really not too difficult.  Once you've generated a .arff file, you can feed this to Weka and run myriad different classifiers on it to figure out what model best fits your data.  If necessary, you can then program this model to operate on your data.

Weka also includes cross-validation which will essentially ensure that the quality of your results will extend beyond the testing data that you are feeding to the program.  In case you're unfamiliar with the concept, it's very easy to overtrain your model and get good results with a specific set of training data, but when testing on other data get much worse results.

Weka .arff file (for reference: Final settlements in labor negotitions in Canadian industry):

```
@relation 'labor-neg-data'
@attribute 'duration' real
@attribute 'wage-increase-first-year' real
@attribute 'wage-increase-second-year' real
@attribute 'wage-increase-third-year' real
@attribute 'cost-of-living-adjustment' {'none','tcf','tc'}
@attribute 'working-hours' real
@attribute 'pension' {'none','ret_allw','empl_contr'}
@attribute 'standby-pay' real
@attribute 'shift-differential' real
@attribute 'education-allowance' {'yes','no'}
@attribute 'statutory-holidays' real
@attribute 'vacation' {'below_average','average','generous'}
@attribute 'longterm-disability-assistance' {'yes','no'}
@attribute 'contribution-to-dental-plan' {'none','half','full'}
@attribute 'bereavement-assistance' {'yes','no'}
@attribute 'contribution-to-health-plan' {'none','half','full'}
@attribute 'class' {'bad','good'}
@data
1,5,?,?,?,40,?,?,2,?,11,'average',?,?,'yes',?,'good'
2,4.5,5.8,?,?,35,'ret_allw',?,?,'yes',11,'below_average',?,'full',?,'full','good'
?,?,?,?,?,38,'empl_contr',?,5,?,11,'generous','yes','half','yes','half','good'
2,2,2,?,'none',40,'none',?,?,'no',11,'average','yes','none','yes','full','bad'
1,2,?,?,'tc',40,'ret_allw',4,0,'no',11,'generous','no','none','no','none','bad'
1,2.8,?,?,'none',38,'empl_contr',2,3,'no',9,'below_average','yes','half',?,'none','bad'
```

Where ? identifies missing/unknown data point.

Comment: I would add that it's also crucial to decide what model are you going to use to extract the concrete features. A simple initial approach could be for example a [bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model).

Comment: Thanks steve. As i know I can't directly input text data into a neural network. Can I use weka to preprocess text data?

Comment: To my knowledge, weka can only read in .arff and .csv. If you have data in some other form, you need to compute feature vectors for each datum and output them to one of the affiliated file types. When I get home, I'll attach a sample .arff file (many samples are also included when you download weka).

Comment: updated my answer.  Hope that helps a little bit.  The set of youtube tutorials was pretty helpful, too.

Comment: No problem. Could you please accept/upvote my answer? You're not going to get anything else for this question.  If you still need to know more, you're going to have to ask a more detailed question, usually one that highlights a problem in some bit of code that you provide for people to look at/hopefully fix.

Comment: I have able to create an arff file from my text file. Is there any java libraries which I can use arff file to do the text classification?

Comment: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code